# Permutation data structure

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, permutation

I'm in need of some assistance regarding permutations.

My problem is this: In our system we have various devices running various software components. Im interested in finding all the permutations (unique combinations) of the versions of said components, and end up with a list of tuples or structs ala this

```
struct Permutation
{
    IComparable Software1{ get; set; }
    IComparable Software2{ get; set; }
    IComparable Software3{ get; set; } 
}
```

Then end up with a list like this:

```
Software1: v1
Software2: v1
Software3: v1

Software1: v1
Software2: v2
Software3: v1

Software1: v2
Software2: v1
Software3: v1
```

The software exists on various components organized in a tree structure (Node->Item). The type of the child node tells me which kind of software to look up

```
 Node->Root (L0)
    Node->Parent (L1) 
       Node->ChildType1 (L2): has property Software1, Software2
       Node->ChildType2 (L2): has property Software3
```

I can easily navigate the tree with `node.Children` (`IList<Node>`) and `node.Parent` (`Node`).

I want to inorder-iterate the tree and build a list of all permutations. Is there a good existing data structure in the .net framework which I can use for this, or does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve it?

Comment: you should show some code; it is too hard to figure out what the tree has got to do with permuting for me now\

Comment: I just wrote about a generic tree structure the other day on my site. Maybe that will help. [Generic Visitor Pattern](http://www.segerlabs.com/generic-visitor-pattern.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My thoughts would be along these lines:

```
    var list = from parent in root.Parents()
               select new Permutation
                  {
                      Software1 = parent.ChildA.Software1,
                      Software2 = parent.ChildA.Software2,
                      Software3 = parent.ChildB.Software3,
                  };

    foreach (var perm in list.Distinct())
    {
       // do something 
    }
```

You'll want to make sure that Permutation is comparable and equatable just fine:

```
struct Permutation : IEquatable<Permutation>, IComparable<Permutation>
{
    public IComparable Software1 { get; set; }
    public IComparable Software2 { get; set; }
    public IComparable Software3 { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Permutation other)
    {
        return Equals(other.Software1, Software1) && Equals(other.Software2, Software2) && Equals(other.Software3, Software3);
    }

    public int CompareTo(Permutation other)
    {
        int cmp = 0;
        if (0 == cmp) cmp = other.Software1.CompareTo(Software1);
        if (0 == cmp) cmp = other.Software2.CompareTo(Software2);
        if (0 == cmp) cmp = other.Software3.CompareTo(Software3);
        return cmp;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (obj.GetType() != typeof(Permutation)) return false;
        return Equals((Permutation)obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int result = (Software1 != null ? Software1.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (Software2 != null ? Software2.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result * 397) ^ (Software3 != null ? Software3.GetHashCode() : 0);
            return result;
        }
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Permutation left, Permutation right)
    {
        return left.Equals(right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Permutation left, Permutation right)
    {
        return !left.Equals(right);
    }
}
```

I used resharper to do the legwork there :)

Comment: @havardhu: don't forget about the comparer (by default Distinct() uses the default implementation provided by the [`Default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx) property of the `EqualityComparer<T>` generic class which is why I made the struct implement `IEquatable<Permutation>`